# Turtle-watching in Costa Rica and Panama in April

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, central-america, costa-rica, panama

Where can I watch the turtles lay their eggs in Costa Rica and Panama in the second half of April? I am mainly interested in places that are accessible by car (4x4 is fine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least 2 tours that I could find that could fit your criteria:

[Undiscovered Carribean](http://www.seeturtles.org/1624/undiscovered-caribbean.html)

and

[LeatherBack Volunteer Vacation](http://www.seethewild.org/541/40/costa-rica-leatherback-turtles-volunteer-vacation.html)

I am sure that you could probably get to those beaches on your own if you choose to but I think these would be better.  There is actually a whole slew of tours just like those at [SeeTurtles.org](http://www.seeturtles.org)

**EDIT**

[More on Turtle Watching in Costa Rica](http://www.adventureincostarica.com/activities_turtles.php)

[And Even more on Turtle Watching including a map](http://www.travelexcellence.com/costa-rica-ecotourism/turtle-watching)

[And with the best map I could find](http://www.anywherecostarica.com/maps/turtle-nesting)

Answer (score 2):

We ended up watching the leatherback turtles on the Gandoca beach. This was organized through an agency in Puero Viejo de Talamanca (I can't remember the name of the agency). I can certainly recommend this option, and after reading more about turtle watching I think it is actually get by far the highest probability of success in April.